# How many requeries/second can my server handle?

Tags: mysql

I have a dedicated server and my provider doesn't want to tell me how many requeries/second MySQL can handle.

Is this just in relation with MySQL or also with other *things*?

Operating system: **CentOS 6.5 with Parallels Plesk 12 (64-bit)**
server: **UNIX socket**
version: **5.1.73**

I can provide more info if asked, thank you.

Comment: If you think logically, what part, besides software, has to do with how many requests per second something can do? Could it be hardware? Could it be the type of request? It's not like every request is the same, is it? It's only natural that they **can't** tell you. They don't know unless they **measure** it. And measuring something like that isn't trivial as you may think.

Comment: I can't use cron, so I use `setInterval` to search with ajax every second new notifications to display + the website is linked with C++ program that also fetches every second in MySQL. So without user, C++ MySQL every second + per user 1 request/second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It answer is - It depends on many many many factors. How many cubes can you fit in a box is a similar question in a non technical sense.

What are the queries, What are the specs of the server, is it dedicated mysql or does your webserver go on there too, Is it overclocked any ? Whats the temperature ? Do you cache querys ?

The list goes on. The best answer is to just test it with your set up and a similar set of queries and see. We can not give a better answer

Comment: Is saying "we can't give you an answer" really an answer?

Comment: @PatrickQ - it is. The answer is backed up with facts on why the concrete answer can't be given.

Comment: If to many factors come in other, then better question would be: how can I see when the server begins to be overloaded?

Comment: @N.B. I'm not sure I see "facts" in that answer. I see an anecdote and more questions. The core of the "answer" is simply "it depends", which I'm not sure is a high-quality answer. FWIF, I think your (N.B.) comment is more of an answer than this.

Comment: Sorry i thought i commented

Comment: @gr3g - that's also another tricky question because you can have issues with CPU (very easy to handle) or problems with hard drive I/O capabilities (when it comes to databases). This (usually) boils down to periodic server querying to see what's going on with CPU, RAM and HDD. And as you can see, this is why this question should be moved to either dba or superuser SXE sites.